# Rails + Emberjs: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm new to using rails as an api with an Emberjs front-end. I'm getting a 'Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity' and Can't verify CSRF token authenticity whenever I try to do a POST request

I've seen a couple of posts and solutions saying to insert this function

```
$(function() {
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    return $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    });
});
```

Where is the appropriate place to implement CSRF in an ember-cli project?

**UPDATE: 10/1/2015**

my app/adapters/application.js looks something like this now:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  headers: Ember.computed(function(){
    var token = Ember.$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    return {"X-CSRF-Token": token};
  })
});
```

However, i'm still getting the same error messages...

Comment: You should add this in your application adapter - you can use the `headers` hash to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to add this to your manifest file:

```
#= require jquery-ujs
```

Or you could extend your application adapter to always include CSRF token:

```
ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  headers:
    "X-CSRF-Token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

Comment: yes, the one that is in the `app/assets/javascripts`